# Replace / Change .aspx page at runtime

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use DNN with AngularJS and bootstrap. Now I have a page layout in the form of

[image]

What I want now is, according to a function of what the user selects in the menu must master and detail to be replaced.
There are different .aspx pages that I would have to add at runtime.

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "replace" the .ASPX page - you can request HTML from different endpoints (pages, if you will) and ASP.NET would generate them based on the request.

That linguistic inaccuracy aside, you'd need to have your client Angular app render different templates based on some selection value. You can use `ng-include` and link to a template URL, which could be generated by your .ASPX page.

So, imagine you have a simple HTML page like this:

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-change="changeMasterAndDetail()">
   <option value="foo">foo</option> 
   <option value="bar">bar</option>
</select>

<div ng-include="master"></div>
<div ng-include="detail"></div>
```

In the controller, you can assign the template Url depending on the selection:

```
.controller("SelectionCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.selection = foo;
   $scope.changeMasterAndDetail = changeMasterAndDetail;

   changeMasterAndDetail();

   function changeMasterAndDetail(){
      if ($scope.selection === "foo"){
         $scope.master = "/path/to/master/pageA.aspx";
         $scope.detail = "/path/to/detail/pageA.aspx";
      } else if ($scope.selection === "bar"){
         $scope.master = "/path/to/master/pageB.aspx";
         $scope.detail = "/path/to/detail/pageB.aspx";
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Looks okay, what i found was the way with angular-ui-router.min.js and changing the sites via $state.transitionTo. But it looks like a bad way for me.

Comment: That would work too. It depends on what you are really trying to build, which is not clear from the original post

Comment: I use DotnetNuke and programming in angularJS with bootstrap. Uses ng-table, ng-tree and others.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure what to do with this information :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to replace the content of **details** on the basis of the click of the menu items in the **master** section , you only need to put a `<a href = "destinationURL">Option</a>` .

You can create a master page where you keep the master section and all your tabs or options in them along with the `href` having the URL of your content page.

You should also add a `<ContentPlaceHolder>` in your master page where in the content of the details page will go.

Now, when you create a new page , you choose the master page and simply start writing content in the `<asp:Content>` area. By this all your content will appear in the **details** area. And that area will be loaded dynamically based on the `href`  .